# Where to install my HDD (harddisk) in my pc case?

Tags: hard-drive, desktop-computer, case

I have a `FSP CMT340 aRGB` pc case, when it's opened it looks like:

[image]

I would like to install an HDD in my PC, but I don't know how and where to install it.

I was thinking to unscrew one of the expansion slots of my case, but even then it's a bit unclear as to where to install the HDD in my pc case.

Is it possible to install HDD in this pc case and if so where do I put it?

Comment: Have you done even minimal research before asking this? Do you have the packaging? Do you have a manual? This review indicates pretty clearly that the drive cages are at the bottom: https://www.tweaktown.com/reviews/8991/fsp-cmt340-addressable-rgb-mid-tower-chassis-review/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The info is right there on [FSP's page for the 340](https://www.fsplifestyle.com/en/product/CMT340.html)

Two drives will fit on the top of the lower bulkhead[the mounts are visible in your photo]…

[image]

& two underneath it - accessed from the rear.

[image]